# Change the Cell Color based on 4 Cells value in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting, vba

I have following table and I want to build a conditional formatting or Macro to highlight the cell value column A if following criteria is not meeting..

if all column values are Yes > all good.. no action required.
if Column B, C or D value is "No"; check Column A Cell value for "NO"; if it is different, change the background color of Column A Cell value as red.

similarly, if Column B,C, and Column Values are "Yes" but Column A cell value is "NO";  change the background color of Column A cell value as Red.

here is an example:

```
StablePlan  CaseCount   StockCount  TotalCount
Yes         Yes         Yes         Yes
Yes         Yes         No          Yes
No          Yes         Yes         Yes
No          Yes         Yes         No
Yes         Yes         Yes         Yes
```

Currently using (but not working):

```
=OR($A3="NO",$B3="No",$C3="No",$D3="No")
```

Comment: Cool. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Try conditional formatting.

Comment: Yes.. I did.. I have tried with conditional formatting but I could give only one rule to highlight if there is a value of "No" in these 4 columns.. it is highlighting the entire row..

Comment: =OR($A3="NO",$B3="No",$C3="No",$D3="No")

Comment: Why are you even bothering with conditional formatting let alone a [tag:macro]? The proper COUNTIF formula in column would guarantee the results.

Comment: @AämërMöhammëd - please do not post addendums to your question in comments. Edit your original post to include them.

Comment: Sure @Jeeped.. it will not be repeated.. Sorry for the inconvinience caused..

z32a7ul, vityata - thanks for the clue.. it has worked for I have updated my formula and it is working now.. 

=AND(OR($B3="No",$C3="No",$D3="No",$E3="No"),$AF3="Yes")

Answer (score 3):

If you **must** have a red alert cell in column A, create a conditional formatting rule based upon the following formula.

```
=OR(AND($A2="yes", COUNTIF($B2:$D2, "no")), AND($A2="no", COUNTIF($B2:$D2, "yes")=3))
```

[image]

However, it seems to me that the correct formula in column A would guarantee the results. Put this in A2,

```
=IF(COUNTIF(B2:D2, "yes")=3, "Yes", "No")
```

Fill down. It seems to me that you will never get an incorrect response result in column A.

Comment: I agree.. but the Column A Value is also a check we have compare against the values in column B, C, and D... I have tried given formula but it seems not working.. if there is a NO value in B, C & D columns; the value of A column should also be No.. if it is Yes then it should get highlighted..

Comment: You changed the scope of the question when you posted the working formula into your last comment. The latter formula above would have to be modified to `=IF(COUNTIF(B3:E3, "yes")=4, "Yes", "No")` and put in AF3.

Comment: Back to your comment: that is taken care of with the `AND($A2="yes", COUNTIF($B2:$D2, "no"))` part. It is TRUE is A2 is "Yes" and there is at least one "No" in B2:D2.

Comment: Thank you so much.. it works.. I was modifying the give formula to suit to my actual issue and still using the last (column count) as 3.. that is the reason it was not working.. I have changed it to correct value now and it works.. Thank You so much for your help...